# change data in nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to use an javascript algorithm to convert the data from products mode to reward mode, please help me :

```
var products = [{
  id: "65864",name_fa:"پک دفتر 40 برگ وزيري شوميز کلاسيک 40 ",
 details:[{master: 5,slave: 0,slave2: 0},{master: 11,slave: 0,slave2: 0}]
},{
id: 67532,name_fa: "100-بازی لونا",
 details:[{master: 0,slave: 5,slave2: 0}]
}]
```

TO :

```
 reward: [
        {products: [
                {
                    id: "65864",
                    name_fa:"پک دفتر 40 برگ وزيري شوميز کلاسيک 40" ,
                     "master": "5",
                    "slave": "0",
                    "slave2": "0"  
                },
                  {
                    "id": "67532",
                    "name_fa":"100-بازی لونا" ,
                     "master": "0",
                    "slave": "5",
                    "slave2": "0"
                }
            ],
        },
         {"products": [
                {
                    "id": "65864",
                    "name_fa":"پک دفتر 40 برگ وزيري شوميز کلاسيک 40" ,
                     "master": "11",
                    "slave": "0",
                    "slave2": "0"
                },
                  {
                    "id": "67532",
                    "name_fa":"100-بازی لونا" ,
                     "master": "0",
                    "slave": "5",
                    "slave2": "0"
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
```

example:

[1,2],[3]

to

[1,3],[2,3]

I am trying to use an javascript algorithm to convert the data from products mode to reward mode, please help me

Comment: do you have always only two products inside `products`? what if more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called cartesian product. I'm reusing a function and apply it on 2 arrays. The products, and the details. Then I combine those arrays (should be same length) into the required result.

```js
// from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234242/3807365
function cartesianProduct(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.map(function(x) {
      return b.map(function(y) {
        return x.concat([y]);
      })
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b)
    }, [])
  }, [
    []
  ])
}

var products = [{
  id: "65864",
  name_fa: "پک دفتر 40 برگ وزيري شوميز کلاسيک 40 ",
  details: [{
    master: 5,
    slave: 0,
    slave2: 0
  }, {
    master: 11,
    slave: 0,
    slave2: 0
  }]
}, {
  id: 67532,
  name_fa: "100-بازی لونا",
  details: [{
    master: 0,
    slave: 5,
    slave2: 0
  }]
}];

var input = products.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg.push(item.details);
  return agg;
}, []);
var a = cartesianProduct(input);

// same for the id and names
var input2 = products.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  var ids = []
  item.details.forEach(function(_) {
    ids.push({
      id: item.id,
      name_fa: item.name_fa
    })
  })
  agg.push(ids);
  return agg;
}, []);
var b = cartesianProduct(input2);

//console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2));
//console.log(b)

var reward = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var newGroup = {
    products: []
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
    var newMan = {}
    newGroup.products.push({
      ...b[i][j],
      ...a[i][j]

    })
  }
  reward.push(newGroup)

}
console.log(reward)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```